# Entity Framework decimal problem on insert after publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, decimal

I have a data model named Gold with a decimal property for the price of gold like this:

```
public class Gold
{
  [key]
  public int GoldId { get; set; }
  public decimal RateValue { get; set; }
}
```

I know that EF decimal default precision and scale is (18,2) and this is enough for me. I don't want to change it and I do not have any problem on insert decimal values on localhost.
But after publishing my website on a host, when I try to insert a decimal like 1210.40 it does not insert or sometimes it inserts 1210.00 (with wrong scale) in db without any error!

I completely confused because I don't have this problem on local running of my code.
No problem with decimals like 1210 without the right of dot digits!!!

This is my code for insert a decimal:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="RateValue")]Gold manualPrices)
{
  Gold ons = new Gold() {RateValue=(decimal)manualPrices.RateValue,};
            db.GoldRepository.Insert(ons);
            db.Save();
}
```

Razor Code:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RateValue, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

more info: I am using MVC .Net Framework 4.5.2 , Code first, Unit of Work, MS SQL 2016.

Comment: What is the cultural setting of the host?

Comment: I have changed culture in Global by this code:

protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var persianCulture = new PersianCulture();
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = persianCulture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = persianCulture;
        }

Comment: I assume `{RateValue=(decimal)manualPrices.onsRateValue}` is a typo (the property is named `RateValue` not `onsRateValue`). And its already a `decimal` so you do not need to cast it to a `decimal` again - should be just `{ RateValue=manualPrices.RateValue }`

Comment: Your right, it's a typo here. RateValue is correct in my code. I've already edited it. Thank you. But if i do not cast it again to decimal i get an error and i don't know why!

Comment: @MahshidFatemi. That suggests you might have a culture issue. What is the culture on the server, and what is the character used by that culture for the decimal separator (e.g. dot, comma)? - the code you have shown will work fine without the cast if its one that accepts a `.` (dot) as the decimal separator

Comment: @MahshidFatemi This issue occurs because client and host (server) cultural settings use different decimal seperator characters. For example if I run your code with US regional settings (dot for decimal seperator) and value 1245.40 everything works fine. But when I change my regional settings to Persian (/ for decimal seperator) manualPrices.RateValue doesn't even get binded. Because binder can not identify the incoming value as a decimal. You have to handle the difference between the client and host cultural settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @StephenMuecke and @heuristican

The culture have been changed to Persian culture in global. This affects the character used for the decimal separator from dot(.) to slash (/) so decimals with dot as separator don't even bind.

Nothing changed in code. Just typing decimals like 1210/40 instead of 1210.40 for insert. Problem solved.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that all your clients will be using Persian cultural settings? If that's not the case you still have to handle different cultural settings.

Comment: yes, I am sure because the page contains inserting data is in admin area and there are few admins for my website all using Persian culture.